Post Angular 17 Upgrade ng start fails in webpack
We have recently upgraded from angular 12 to angular 17, post this when we are trying to build/ run the application, always getting following two errors.
./src/main.ts - Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/ivy/index.js):
Error: Cannot resolve type entity i7.IconsModule to symbol
./src/polyfills.ts - Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/ivy/index.js):
Error: Cannot resolve type entity i7.IconsModule to symbol
Now, what is this IconsModule, we have never used something of this kind in the code.
Following are the dependencies in package.json file
"@angular/animations": "^17.3.1",
"@angular/cdk": "^17.3.2",
"@angular/common": "^17.3.2",
"@angular/compiler": "^17.3.1",
"@angular/core": "^17.3.1",
"@angular/elements": "^17.3.1",
"@angular/forms": "^17.3.1",
"@angular/localize": "^17.3.1",
"@angular/material": "^17.3.2",
"@angular/material-moment-adapter": "^17.3.2",
"@angular/platform-browser": "^17.3.1",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^17.3.1",
"@angular/router": "^17.3.1",
"@apollo/client": "3.6.9",
"@azure/msal-angular": "^3.0.13",
"@azure/msal-browser": "^3.10.0",
"@fullcalendar/angular": "6.1.10",
"@fullcalendar/core": "6.1.10",
"@fullcalendar/daygrid": "6.1.10",
"@fullcalendar/interaction": "6.1.10",
"@microsoft/applicationinsights-web": "^3.1.2",
"@microsoft/microsoft-graph-client": "^3.0.5",
"@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^16.0.0",
"@progress/kendo-angular-buttons": "^15.3.0",
"@progress/kendo-angular-charts": "^15.3.0",
"@progress/kendo-angular-common": "^15.3.0",
"@progress/kendo-angular-dateinputs": "^15.3.0",
"@progress/kendo-angular-dialog": "^15.3.0",
"@progress/kendo-angular-dropdowns": "^15.3.0",
"@progress/kendo-angular-excel-export": "^15.3.0",
"@progress/kendo-angular-grid": "^15.3.0",
"@progress/kendo-angular-inputs": "^15.3.0",
"@progress/kendo-angular-intl": "^15.3.0",
"@progress/kendo-angular-l10n": "^15.3.0",
"@progress/kendo-angular-label": "^15.3.0",
"@progress/kendo-angular-layout": "^15.3.0",
"@progress/kendo-angular-navigation": "^15.5.0",
"@progress/kendo-angular-pager": "^15.3.0",
"@progress/kendo-angular-pdf-export": "^15.3.0",
"@progress/kendo-angular-popup": "^15.3.0",
"@progress/kendo-angular-progressbar": "^15.3.0",
"@progress/kendo-angular-tooltip": "^15.3.0",
"@progress/kendo-angular-treeview": "^15.3.0",
"@progress/kendo-angular-upload": "^15.3.0",
"@progress/kendo-angular-utils": "^15.5.0",
"@progress/kendo-data-query": "^1.7.0",
"@progress/kendo-drawing": "^1.19.1",
"@progress/kendo-licensing": "^1.3.5",
"@progress/kendo-theme-default": "~7.2.1",
"@types/minimatch": "^5.1.2",
"@types/moment": "^2.13.0",
"@types/moment-timezone": "^0.5.30",
"@types/regenerator-runtime": "^0.13.1",
"@webcomponents/custom-elements": "~1.6.0",
"angular-d3-charts": "^5.0.0",
"angular-pipes": "^10.0.0",
"angular-user-idle": "4.0.0",
"angular2-uuid": "^1.1.1",
"apollo-angular": "^6.0.0",
"bootstrap": "^4.6.2",
"core-js": "2.6.5",
"crypto-js": "^4.1.1",
"document-register-element": "~1.7.2",
"file-saver": "^2.0.5",
"font-awesome": "~4.7.0",
"graphql": "^16.0.0",
"hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
"jquery": "^3.6.1",
"json5": "^2.2.2",
"jsonwebtoken": "^9.0.0",
"jszip": "^3.10.1",
"jszip-utils": "^0.1.0",
"moment": "^2.29.4",
"moment-timezone": "^0.5.39",
"ng-multiselect-dropdown": "^0.2.14",
"ngx-cookie-service": "^17.1.0",
"ngx-file-drop": "^16.0.0",
"ngx-order-pipe": "^2.2.0",
"ngx-toastr": "^18.0.0",
"pdfmake": "^0.2.2",
"powerbi-client": "^2.21.0",
"powerbi-client-angular": "^3.0.5",
"rxjs": "7.8.1",
"rxjs-compat": "~6.6.7",
"semver": "^7.5.2",
"stream": "0.0.2",
"sweetalert2": "~8.11.7",
"tslib": "^2.4.1",
"xlsx": "https://cdn.sheetjs.com/xlsx-0.20.0/xlsx-0.20.0.tgz",
"zone.js": "^0.14.4"
I have searched a lot. There is solution like including "preserveSymlinks": true in tsconfig.lib.json. Unfortunately its not working for me.
also, tried deleting node modules folder and clearing npm cache
Any help on this will be welcome.

Could you share your polyfills.ts and main.ts? Since angular 17.1's application builder now supports custom loaders, there's like a massive chance someone removed the IconsModule from their library alltogether...

Hi, thanks for your response main.ts
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { AppModule } from './app/app.module';
import { environment } from './environments/environment';
if (environment.production) {
enableProdMode();
}
platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule)
.catch(err => console.error(err));

and polyfills.ts
import '@angular/localize/init';
import 'zone.js';  // Included with Angular CLI.
import '@webcomponents/custom-elements/src/native-shim';
import '@webcomponents/custom-elements/custom-elements.min';
import 'regenerator-runtime/runtime';
